# I have AIs in people's heads. One AI is mischievous. What is a subtle way the AI can mess with its user?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, brain, vision, illusion

As it stands currently, there are some people in my world with a neural interface, that replaces one of their eyes. And an AI connects to it. Details aside, the AI can:

1. Read the user's mind
2. Speak to the user privately, directly into their head
3. Give user sight as a replacement for their one missing eye
4. Enhance user's sight, by highlighting something or changing something
5. Connect wirelessly to a nearby friendly device
6. Increase the amount of data that go through the neural interface, to force the user's brain to accept the artificial eye as the dominant eye
7. Increase the amount of data even more, making the user's brain “forget” that they have one healthy eye (users don't like this)

One AI is more mischievous than others. I'm looking for ideas how to let that AI mess with its user(s) in a subtle, non-violent, meaningless way. The user must not catch up with the prank early on, which limits most methods to occuring on the side with user's artificial eye, unless the AI increases the data thoroughput. So far, here are my ideas:

1. Slightly alter the color of an object
2. Increase or decrease the size of an object
3. An object absorbs color
4. An object moves closer to the user everytime the user looks at it
5. Object is temporarily hidden from the user
6. Rats darting around in user's peripheal vision
7. Sunsets are more vibrant
8. User hears rain coming from outside, but it's a sunny day
9. User hears footsteps behind them
10. Mirrors reflect something different
11. Adjust paintings/statues of people so that their eyes always look at the user
12. A room is filled with non-existent light coming from the windows
13. Shadows dance as if they were created by a fire, rather than by an electric lamp
14. During midday, prolong all shadows to make it seem like it's evening already
15. User sees rain, and the user is the only one bothered by it
16. Deja vu, think Matrix black cat scene
17. Vision is out of sync and delayed. The user hears someone placing their mug on the table a split second before they see them placing the mug down

Comment: Hi, Dalibor. Stack Exchange isn't suited for brainstorming questions, and you aren't supposed to answer your own questions within the question. This will likely be closed. If you would like to ask something more specific, it would benefit all of us.

Comment: AI: "I swear it wasn't me you've got stuck tune syndrome btw do you want to upgrade the plan for an ad free experience?"

Comment: AI has hallucinations. This is part of the current crop of chat AI. So, you don't even need to call it mischievous. "Oh, my eye is off on another wild trip and giving me distorted images."

Comment: I agree with the close vote, but I also agree with the down votes. "AI" is just window dressing since it doesn't exist in this form, so you should have performed your due diligence with research (you didn't, hence the down votes). You should have studied auditory hallucination (voices in my head!) and religion (I'm a believer... but to be honest for the purpose of the discussion, voices in my head!) and marketing (voices in my head!) and pathological manipulation (voices in my head!), and education science (voices!) any or all of which would have answered this question.

Answer (score 2):

**Subliminals**

The AI whispers things to the user while they're asleep subtly twisting their thinking and manipulating them. Doesn't happen while awake.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subliminal_stimuli

Answer (score 1):

- When the host is looking at a USB, the artificial eye might flip which side of the USB the person sees so they have 50/50 odds of putting it in incorrectly the first time. Sometimes it doesn't do this so that the host never knows whether it's accurate or not.
- Randomly pretends there are typos in every fifth word the host types; maybe the letters that constitute the the typos spell out a message.
- Misrepresents the length of finger/toenails, then shows them correctly when the host takes out clippers. Only does this about a week after last clipping so that it's plausible.
- Puts fake hair over the host's artificial eye until the host reaches up to brush it out of the way. May also do the same with a housefly that always seems to be buzzing around that side of the host's head.
- Switches around the digits on keypads the host is using.
- Airbrushes [glare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glare_(vision)) effects onto lights it doesn't like the host looking at, even really soft ones like bedside lamps.
- The artificial eye always "sees" a large and hairy insect in the host's boot that persists even when said boot is held upside down and shaken. The real eye doesn't.

Comment: The USB idea is a good one. Just when they get suspicious that the AI might be helping them get it right in less than three tries, let them get it wrong. Of course, that requires the AI to be able to figure out the correct orientation, which may be an unsolvable problem.